# How does NPM manage node_modules Transitive Dependencies?

Tags: node.js, npm

Let’s say I create an app called *`MyApp`* and it depends on package *`A` (version **1.0**)* and package *`B`* which depends on package *`C`* which in turn depends on package *`A` (version **2.0**)*:

```
MyApp
- A @ 1.0
- B

A
- (no dependencies in whichever version)

B
- C

C
- A @ 2.0
```

My question is.

Q1 - Which version of the package *`A`* will be installed? Will package A get installed or *`MyApp`’s* node_modules,  `B`’s node_modules or `C`’s node_modules?

Q2 - My thinking is, NPM will install *`A (1.0)`* in *`MyApp`'s* node_modules folder and install *`A (2.0)`* on package *`C`'s* node_modules.

Q3 - But if I just want **one** copy of *`A (2.0)`* to be installed **globally**, what should I do to make NPM do in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering solely documentation at https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/folders#cycles-conflicts-and-folder-parsimony, your Q2 assumptions are right, what also answers Q1.

> […] at every stage, if a package is already installed in an ancestor `node_modules` folder, then it is not installed at the current location.

For illustration, let's modify your example and add *`A (1.0)`* also as a dependency of *`B`*:

```
MyApp
- A @ 1.0
- B

A
- (no dependencies in whichever version)

B
- A @ 1.0 (added for illustration)
- C

C
- A @ 2.0
```

Resulting directory tree with respective versions (that are NOT part of the folder names) should then look like this:

```
MyApp/node_modules/A (@ 1.0)
MyApp/node_modules/B
MyApp/node_modules/B/node_modules/C
MyApp/node_modules/B/node_modules/C/node_modules/A (@ 2.0)
```

NB: there is NO

```
MyApp/node_modules/B/node_modules/A (@ 1.0)
```

present there, since it is already present higher, under *`MyApp`*.

(Side note: in case *`B`* would not depend on *`A (1.0)`*, from the docs I am not completely sure, whether the *`A (@ 2.0)`* wouldn't appear one level higher (under *`B`*) instead, as *`B`* would be the *first top-most ancestor without version mismatch*, even though it was not *`B`'s* dependency at all in this hypothetical case. This would allow all *"siblings"* share same module without colliding with root level dependency.)

As for Q3 the answer is simple (I guess by "global" you mean *`MyApp`* (root) module, not system-wide modules): since *you* dictate *`MyApp`'s* dependencies, if the app can work with *`A (2.0)`*, just bump up that dependency version from `1.0` and do the update. After that there should only be

```
MyApp/node_modules/A (@ 2.0)
```

instead of `.. (@ 1.0)` and the former

```
MyApp/node_modules/B/node_modules/C/node_modules/A (@ 2.0)
```

should be gone.

If it was other way round (*`C`* would depend on *older* *`A (1.0)`* instead of newer `2.0`) then I don't have a clear answer, besides *you would just have to make `C` author unlock or bump-up dependency to `A (2.0)`*, i.e. I don't think it is possible without altering those modules.